# Change Contact's ZIP/Postal Code field length

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to change ZIP/Postal Code field length. I've changed Maximum Length from 20 to 100 chars, saved customization and published it. But when I'm trying to save or update the record on CRM form with Postal Code larger than 50 chars I'm getting error:

```C#
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Generic SQL error.Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ErrorCode>-2147204784</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails 
    xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Generic SQL error.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2013-10-04T13:57:19.13039Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Same thing when updating record with `CrmOrganizationServiceContext`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what was the error before increasing the length?

Comment: I would recommend to check Trace.

Comment: there was no error, change length of field is a new requirement from customer

Comment: _I would recommend to check Trace._ - Can I do that in CRM-online, There are no plugins/workflows on Customer Create/Update.

Comment: Sorry, I though you are working on OnPremises. Not sure it we can enable trace on online or not because I don't have much experience of Online CRM. Just found this into from a forum that you can request support to turn dev errors on for you by calling them.

Comment: if you are in CRM-online open a ticket to microsoft, looks like it's a platform issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not able to store more than 50 characters in the postalcode field, no matter what is configured in the user interface. To be clear, the user interface will let you enter a large field size (in your case 100) but the field in the underlying SQL database (`CustomerAddressBase.PostalCode`) will not grow beyond 50, even if you customize the `Address` entity to make the field size larger.

Not sure if this is intentional by design or a bug in Dynamics CRM, you would need to contact Microsoft to determine if it can be fixed. I can tell you that this does not appear to be documented anywhere in the CRM SDK documentation for the [CustomerAddress entity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328405.aspx).

I tested this in an on-premises installation and it has has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Early Bound Entity Classes? If so you will need to rebuild them using crmsvutil.

Comment: Thanks for advise, but I'm getting this error on CRM form too, I'll update my question, sorry for missing this detail.

Comment: Are there any plugins setup to fire on Create/Update for the entity you are using?

Comment: No, there are no plugins/workflows on Customer Create/Update.